# Regular expression for double parentheses

Tags: regex, parentheses

De regular expression below is working fine to find all curly brackets ( '{' and '}' ). But I need to find double parentheses ( '((' and '))' )

```
/\{(((?>[^\{\}]+)|(?R))*)\}/x
```

Anyone who knows how to translate the above regular expression to that?
It's necassary to find parentheses on multilevel. So It needs to find parentheses between parentheses as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be usefull to know which flavour of regular expressions you are using, but there is a good chance that you need to quote `(` and `)` characters, as they have special meaning. So replace `(` with `[(]`, and `)` with `[)]`, or use backslash to quote them.

Comment: Your previous answer did the trick ;) Thank you very much for your help! I simply tried to replace { with (( and } with )), which didn't do the trick (as expected). But this does work:
`/\(\((((?>[^\(\(\)\)]+)|(?R))*)\)\)/x`

Comment: Effectively there are two ways of quoting a special character in regular expressions, one is with backslash (`\ `), another one is putting it into `[]`. However, bear in mind that characters inside square brackets define a *set* of characters to be matched, not a *sequence*.

Comment: Mmm... We experienced some problems with this regex. When we have a sentence like "((We ((love | like)) this shirt (size L)))", then he cannot execute this right. Because of the three parentheses at the end of the sentence. The regex needs to get the first 2 parentheses if it has 3 or more at the beginning, end the last 2 when it has 3 or more parentheses at the end. Is that possible???